# Not able to install juju sync-tools

Tags: juju

I am trying to install juju sync-tools after the juju bootstrap but I am getting this error :

```
wss://10.10.10.103:17070/environment/bdf80612-e98c-468a-8c99-88441c178193/api", will retry: websocket.Dial wss://10.10.10.103:17070/environment/bdf80612-e98c-468a-8c99-88441c178193/api: dial tcp 10.10.10.103:17070: connection refused
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This site is made for answering specific questions about the Ubuntu operating system. What you have here is a glob of text, that without a question, is a very unhelpful piece of information. Please edit your question with more information about your problem if you would like your problem to be solved.